# Behaviour DataInputStream into mapping

Tags: java, arrays, datainputstream

I had problems to save a file into disk.
The path to save, in environment, it's a mapping (the disk is in another server).
**A** - When I try to save a `DataInputStream` with a loop, reading "byte per byte", takes a lot of time (~12 min / MB).
**B**- Now, I read a passing an `byte[8192]`. This solve the problem.
I know that **B** is faster than **A** but, when I run the same code, trying to save into my local disk, there is no difference, both take same time.
Why the mapping takes a lot of time?
Read a `byte[8192]` at a time can cause problems?

Tks!

Comment: Uuuh, wait; why don't you simply use `Files.copy()`?

Comment: I can't. This is Data from WebResponse.

Comment: A `DataInputStream` is an `InputStream` like any other, and there is `Files.copy(InputStream, Path, CopyOption...)`

Comment: Because the network is slower than the local disk, and evidently the network disk doesn't handle single-byte writes as efficiently as the local operating system does. Probably it transmits entire blocks when you write a single byte. You shouldn't be doing that anyway, to either a network or a local drive, and arguably an application shouldn't use network drives at all in the first place. If you must do this kind of I/O, put a buffered stream under the data stream.

Comment: @fge - Yeah, I can use the `Files.copy(InputStream, Path, CopyOption...)`, but I can know why A method is slower.
@EJP - That's right! This was my suspicion. `BufferedInputStream` is better than `DataInputStream`?

Comment: That's not what I said. I said to use both. I'm assuming you have some need to use a data stream. If you don't, don't use it, just use a buffered stream. If you do need it, put a buffered stream underneath it, as I said.